# MIssing TERMINUS_ERROR_LOGGER argument/dependency - NestJS HealthCheck controller

Tags: nestjs, health-check

I'm trying to implement a simple HealtCheck controller in my NestJS api by following the offical example Healthchecks (Terminus): `https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/terminus#setting-up-a-healthcheck` but I'm getting this error:

**Nest can't resolve dependencies of the HealthCheckService (HealthCheckExecutor, ?). Please make sure that the argument TERMINUS_ERROR_LOGGER at index [1] is available in the HealthCheckModule context.**

Since TERMINUS_ERROR_LOGGER seems like some kind of a enum, I'm not able to import it or add it as a provider inside my HealthModule and I haven't found any documentation/blog/post related to this.

Here's my HealthCHeck controller code:

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HealthCheckService, HttpHealthIndicator, HealthCheck, TypeOrmHealthIndicator } from '@nestjs/terminus';

@Controller('health-check')
export class HealthCheckController {

    constructor(
        private readonly health: HealthCheckService,
        private db: TypeOrmHealthIndicator,
    ) { }

    @Get()
    @HealthCheck()
    readiness() {
        return this.health.check([
            async () => this.db.pingCheck('postgres', { timeout: 300 }),
        ]);
    }
}
```

I just want to create a HealtCheck controller to check if the api is connected to my db and implement future health checks.

Comment: Have you imported `TerminusModule` to your module?

Comment: any luck on this? I am very stuck :/

Comment: @PaulSanchez I decided to move along with simple healt checks validations such as:

1. Return a 200 status code with a short message to confirm API is up and running.
2. Return a 200 if the db connection works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had the same error with one difference - it was happening in a Nest `TestingModule`. I'm hoping my solution will help other folks who hit this same issue.

This is using NestJS 10, and I came upon this issue when upgrading a repo from 9 to 10.

Here's what it looked like when the error was happening:

```
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  controllers: [HealthController],
  providers: [
    MemoryHealthIndicator,
    HealthCheckService,
    HealthCheckExecutor,
  ],
}).compile();
```

First attempt to fix it was to import the `TerminusModule` into the test module:

```
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [TerminusModule],
  controllers: [HealthController],
  providers: [
    MemoryHealthIndicator,
    HealthCheckService,
    HealthCheckExecutor,
  ],
}).compile();
```

But that did not change the error. Then I looked at the real module this was testing, and noticed that neither `HealthCheckService` nor `HealthCheckExecutor` were listed as providers there, so I removed those apparently unneeded providers from the array:

```
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [TerminusModule],
  controllers: [HealthController],
  providers: [MemoryHealthIndicator],
}).compile();
```

That did it! **So what I would suggest is taking a look at whatever module is using your `HealthCheckController` and seeing if there are providers that you do not appear to need. You will also need to make sure you're importing the `TerminusModule`.**

(When I experimented and put `HealthCheckService` and `HealthCheckExecutor` in the array of providers on the real module, the same error occurred.)